# Golang: How to disable automatically flag sorting?

Tags: go

With `flag` package, we can specify some command line parameters like this:

```
import "flag"
fun main() {
    from := flag.String("from", "", "the path to be copied")
    to := flag.String("to", "", "where the data copied to")
    ldb := flag.String("db", "./ldb", "the database path used during copy")
    pwd := flag.String("pwd", "", "password to encrypt your data, default no encryption on your data"
    flag.Parse()
    ...
}
```

When use `-h` for help, the printed message seems not the order I provided:

```
-db string
    the database path used during copy (default "./ldb")
-from string
    the path to be copied
-pwd string
    password to encrypt your data, default no encryption on your data
-to string
    where the data copy to
```

the order not intuitive, is there other options to tell Golang: *Don't sort my parameter's automatically!* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output is lexically sorted (https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#VisitAll):

> VisitAll visits the command-line flags in lexicographical order, calling fn for each. It visits all flags, even those not set.

See: https://golang.org/src/flag/flag.go#L435

You could use a `flag.FlagSet` and use a custom `Usage func()`.